# How to Update AngularJS Google Maps Dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently using the [AngularJS Google Maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) plugin to load some markers given a users location

The 'lazy' way of loading the Map is to define it with set coordinates like so

```
<div map-lazy-load="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js">
  <ng-map center="41,-87" zoom="3"></ng-map>
</div>
```

I'll need to update the center coordinates when a user drags the map or provides a city they wish to search. However I'm confused as to how to utilize the `NgMap` object to achieve this

```
  NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
    console.log(map.getCenter());
    console.log('markers', map.markers);
    console.log('shapes', map.shapes);
    // Recenter my map here?
  });
```

Should I create my map with the `NgMap` object first? Or can I somehow use it to update the one I defined on my html page? I see an `addMap()` function belonging to the Object but don't see any information on it in the API

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found what I've needed. Working examples can be found at https://ngmap.github.io/

The `map` instance returned by the `getMap()` function is what I was looking for. This will be the representation of the `<ng-map>` you create.

```
NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
  myMap = map; 
});
```